# How to import an image to Wix Data Collection?

Tags: velo

I have a Wix Collection (visible in the Content Manager) called "Guests", which includes a column of type *Image*. I want to import a CSV file in such a way that an externally-hosted image is uploaded to Wix and saved in this field.

I can import a CSV file with the image column value set to an *external* URL, but the image file is not imported to Wix (i.e. the image file is fetched from the external site every time it is used).

I've tried writing a `myCollection_beforeInsert()` hook to call `wixMediaManager.importFile()` and use the returned `fileUrl`, but Wix doesn't recognise my value as an image.

- If I set it to a string like `'wix:image://v1/{fileUrl}'`, Wix complains "Cell value type is Text."
- If I set it to a JS object like `{ type: 'image', src: 'wix:image://v1/{fileUrl}' }`, Wix complains "Cell value type is JS Object."
- EDIT: when I manually set an image then export to CSV, the format is `'wix:image://v1/{fileUrl}/{fileName}#originWidth={width}&originHeight={height}'`. I tried this but the image width and height are not returned from the `importFile()` method, so it is still recognised as Text.

What are my other options for setting the image field value? The docs are unclear. https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-data.html

[image: error message in Wix Content Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got this working by**

1. **importing a CSV with a "imageUrl" field, then**
2. **importing each file (asynchronously) and**
3. **attaching each imported file to the "image" field of its proper data item.**

First I imported a CSV with a "imageUrl" field.

Then I triggered a piece of code (I put it in a page's `$w.onReady()`, but you can put it anywhere), to call `importFile()` with additional context:

```js
function importImages() {
    wixData.query("myCollection")
        .isEmpty("image")
        .isNotEmpty("imageUrl")
        .find() // max 1000 items
        .then(result => Promise.all(result.items.map(item => {
            return mediaManager.importFile('/images', item.imageUrl, {
                "mediaOptions": {
                    "mediaType": "image"
                },
                "metadataOptions": {
                    "context": {
                        "itemId": item._id // <-- this is how we know which item to update later
                    }
                }
            });
        }));
}
```

And I registered an event listener for Wix's [`onFileUploaded` event](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-media-backend.Events.html#onFileUploaded), to update the image field for the relevant data item.

```js
export function wixMediaManager_onFileUploaded(event) {
    if (event.context.itemId) {
        // get where item._id === event.context.itemId
        return wixData.get("myCollection", event.context.itemId, { suppressAuth: true })
            .then(itemToUpdate => {
                // set the "image" field
                itemToUpdate.image = event.fileInfo.fileUrl;
                return wixData.update("myCollection", itemToUpdate, { suppressAuth: true });
            });
    }
}
```